# setTimeout function in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use set time function if a class exists in the document and that class has some specific data-attributes.So I have started to code in the very generic way and also tried all the  ways even using setTimeout in the function, but not working...

Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    if( jQuery('.conversion-content').length > 0 ){
        var thread_id = jQuery('.conversion-content').attr('data-thread-id');
        var sender = jQuery('.conversion-content').attr('data-sender');
        setTimeout(function(){
            updateConversation(thread_id, sender);
        }, 2000);
    }
    function updateConversation( thread_id, sender ){
        console.log(thread_id,sender);
    }
});
```

Its working for the first time but not working from 2nd time, I had pulled out setTImeout function out of the element checking but no work.

Comment: Why do you need to use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: You need to set the variables inside the timeout function if you want the updated values.

Comment: What do you mean by « not working from 2nd time » ? You set the timeout when the document is ready, so only once per page.

Comment: why would it work for the second time? it's not `setInterval()`

Comment: What do you mean by the "*2nd time*" - second time of what?  2nd time doc.ready runs?  It only runs once, unless you mean 2nd time the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should assign your `thread_id` and `sender` inside the timer, so it would change in time.

Second thing... it does shoot only once, because you are not using `setInterval()`, but `setTimeout()`. Only the first one is repeating in time, the second one delays the execution (once).

Third thing is that if at start `if( jQuery('.conversion-content').length > 0 ){` won't be met, the timer won't even get initialized. So you should put this inside the timer as well.